# How to pause a foreground service

Tags: android, service

I have a service which is a foreground service which runs even when the app is kill. I just wanted to know is there any way I can pause this service when user move to some other activity and resume back when user come back to previous activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to kill **background services** use this .

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
            PackageManager pm;
            pm = getPackageManager();
            //get a list of installed apps.
            packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            String myPackage = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
                if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(myPackage)) continue;
                mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
            }
```